# Why is BufferedWriter not writing to file?

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have this code:

```
    String[] strings = {"Hi" , "You", "He", "They", "Tetrabenzene", "Caaorine", "Calorine"};

    File file = new File("G:\\words.txt");
    FileWriter fWriter;
    BufferedWriter bWriter;

    try {
        if((file.exists())) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);

        //Convert Result objects to JSON and write to file
        for(int j = 0; j < strings.length; ++j) {
            bWriter.write(strings[j]);
                bWriter.newLine();
                System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I have pretty much the same code 2 or 3 times before this and `BufferedWriter` is writing perfectly.  But for some reason when I get to this code it doesn't write.  I've been looking for things that might be wrong but I can't change something and test it quickly as the program takes 10 minutes just to get to this part.

Also, the program prints "done" to the console so I know it is going into the `for loop`.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Close your writers at the end. 
            `bWriter.close();
            fWriter.close();`

Comment: For others who might have a related issue. I had the close statement in the finally block and the BufferedWriter didnt work. When I put the close statement back in the try block it worked again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `bWriter.flush()` when you want your data to actually be flushed to your file on disk. 
Or just call `bWriter.close()` when you're done working with your writer.
The `bWriter.close()` call will call `bWriter.flush()` internally.

Comment: The OP should use a `try-with-resources` if available (Java 7).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to add `if(!file.exists())` rather than `if((file.exists()))`.